# Про преобразование типов

Tags: python

Почему при использовании подобной конструкции

```
print(int("1" * 2))
```

Выводится нормальное значение, а при подобной записи

```
for i in range(2):
    print(int("1" * i))
```

или даже

```
for i in range(2):
    print(int("1" * (int(i) ) ))
```

возникает ошибка

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Не нужно удалять вопрос, лучше напишите собственный ответ к нему. Это может помочь тем, кто столкнется с похожей проблемой

Answer (score 5):

```
'1' * 1 = '1'
'1' * 2 = '11'
'1' * 0 = ''
```

Последнее `int()` не может привести к числу, что логично